# GParted in Ubuntu 18.04 Wayland is not running

Tags: gparted, pkexec

GParted in Ubuntu 18.04 is not running. When I click on GParted, it asks me for a password, then nothing happens and no GParted GUI appears.

When I try to launch GParted from the terminal:

```
$ sudo gparted
[sudo] password for ubuntu-andrew: 
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gpartedbin:14946): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:57:23.758: cannot open display: :0
```

or:

```
$ pkexec gparted 
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway. 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key (gpartedbin:15234): Gtk-WARNING **: 
18:10:11.949: cannot open display: :0
```

I don't know why, but just now I managed to run GParted, but then I logged out of the session and come back, and GParted was not running again.

I pressed Alt+F2 also, but it was of no use. Is there a way to debug this issue like the System Event Log that exists in Windows?

Comment: `gnome-disks` will run on wayland. Install it with `sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: i believe gnome was suppose to run on XORG.. just that now gnome 3, they started to migrate to wayland, because wayland the way it is programmed is easy for future programming.. that's what i read.

Comment: How are you running this, is it from Gnome Terminal, you're not trying to run it from a tty (ctrl+alt+f2, etc.) or something? Did you try `pkexec --user root gparted`? Are you saying @Raffa that `gparted` doesn't run on Wayland.

Comment: @pbhj Yes, I have actually experienced the same issue in the past with `gparted` on wayland at some point in the past. There was an issue [example](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1385556)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to open graphical applications  with `sudo` in Ubuntu 18.04, hence the `Gtk-WARNING **: 17:57:23.758: cannot open display: :0` error message. Instead open GParted with `pkexec` as follows:

```
pkexec gparted
```

and authenticate with your user password in the *Authentication Required* window that opens up.

Try logging in at the usual login screen with Xorg instead of Wayland. Click the gear icon to the left of the  <kbd>Sign In</kbd>  button and select *Ubuntu on Xorg* from the dropdown menu. This selection will be persistent across reboots unless you switch back to Wayland.

[image: select Ubuntu on Xorg]

Comment: $ pkexec gparted
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gpartedbin:15234): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:10:11.949: cannot open display: :0

Comment: Ignore the message, authenticate with your password, and open GParted anyway. It is just a warning.

Comment: Are you sure @karel, "cannot open display: :0" has always in the past been an xauth issue for me. I don't use Wayland yet, AFAIK, so I don't have any knowledge about it, but I'd probably try `xhost si:localuser:root:` to allow root to access the running X session. I notice that in a bug report @Raffa mentions above that a [further bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274451) has two possible fixes for xauth issues with gnome apps, one of which is this `xhost`  command (which you reverse with `xhost -si:localuser:root`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ pkexec gparted
Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(gpartedbin:15234): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:10:11.949: cannot open display: :0
```

same with `pkexec gparted`.

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers. You can edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: Ignore the message, authenticate with your password, and open GParted anyway. it is just a warning.

Comment: hii Karel,  i did entered password. but gparted does not shows up..